# passing _bstr_t between c# and C++ /CLI

Tags: c#, string, c++-cli, marshalling, bstr

I am little confused whether we can use _bstr_t to pass string between c# to C++ and vice versa.

I am using C++/CLI as intermediate layer between C# and C++.

If possible also give example how to marshal it at C# end and C++/CLI end as there are not much documentation around that

Also suggest better data type/ mechanism to pass string.

Comment: Between C# and C++/CLI, you can just use `System::String^`. As for between C++/CLI and native C++, well... what does your native C++ code need?

Comment: I need to pass string in some way to native C++, So how shall i marshal System::String^. Shall i go for char * in native C++ or some other data type? I also need to pass value back to C# from native C++. How shall i do tht?

Comment: You mean native C++ needs std::string?

Comment: It depends on your C++ code and libraries. Which string data structure, character set and encoding would work best? How will the data structure be allocated and freed? If the character set is not what C# uses (Unicode), how do you want to handle a mismatch in each direction?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, this *should* work for converting String^ to string (and it's the easiest way by far). However I cannot test, my VC++2008 Express doesn't find Marshal.h...

```
// TestCppCli2008.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main()
{
    System::String^ s = L"Hello World";

    std::string str = marshal_as<std::string>(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There used to be a website marshal-as dot net where you could download the `marshal_as` template stuff, including overloads to support new data types, which was a way to get it on Express Edition.  Unfortunately it looks like the registration expired and the domain has been co-opted for advertisements...

Comment: BTW, that file should be included in VC++ 2010 Express, just not 2008.